# How to associate two rows for research in an html table

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I'm creating a table with DataTables to display all the data of a project risk. My table looks like :

```
| Owner       | Costs | Probability | Starting date | Ending date |
+-------------+-------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| The name of my risk                                             |
+-------------+-------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| Bruce Wayne | 1000  | 40%         | 01-01-2016    | 01-09-2016  |
+-------------+-------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
```

I didn't list all the data shown in the table but the view looks like I described it, the risk name containing also a link to a page for the modification of the data.

Everything's working great, the sort and the search work perfectly. However, the problem with the search is that it only shows the line containing the specified string so i'm only getting the risk name or its data, never the two at the same time, which is what it want.

I think that there's a possibility to "associate" the rows to get at each time the risk name and its data, not only the name or the data.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7VL3/) does the trick for the sort but I haven't been able yet to make it working in my code. The idea is that I'm looking for the same functionality but for the research.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: My table looks like above. What I want is to "associate" the row containing the name of the risk with the rows containing its data to always have both of them when i'm using the search field offered by datatables.
Currently, the search works but it shows only the line containing the string that i'm looking for. The result I want is the risk name and the risk data for a search, not only the name or only the data. I always want the couple with the following format :
1st line : The risk name / 2nd line : The risk data.




I hope that it it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user from another forum gave me the answer : https://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html

This link details well how to proceed, I've been able to use it very quickly.